# Using OMDB API in R

Tags: r, omdbapi

I am trying to use `OMBP` API in R but not able to use it properly

```
devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/omdbapi")
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)
search_by_title("Captain America")
```

Result:

> Error in search_by_title("Captain America") : 
>     could not find function "search_by_title"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`library(ombdapi)` is missing. Put it after `library(pbapply)`.

You've installed it, so it's available for use, i.e. it's on the hard drive in a place R knows to look *if someone tells R to load the code.* Which is what the `library()` call does.

Comment: I am getting this when I try to use library(ombdapi) Error in library(ombdapi) : there is no package called ‘ombdapi’

Comment: Did your earlier command `devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/omdbapi")` give an error?

Comment: Don't forget to click the green check mark next to the answer, if it is the correct answer.